# Can I connect a remote client socket to .NET listening socket on Azure Windows 10 Pro virtual machine?

Tags: .net, windows, azure, sockets

Is it possible to connect my iOS app's client socket to my .NET listening socket on my Azure Windows 10 Pro virtual machine?

Or, will this only work if VM is Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

- ***You can surely connect your iOS app’s client socket to the .NET listening socket on your Azure Windows 10 Pro VM by configuring the iOS application code in Azure to forward the data/traffic through the application gateway to you desired port on the Azure VM used by the .NET application running on it***.
  As for an app service with some API code in the background for an iOS app frontend, the app service can be configured to expose on a private IP in your virtual network and then further configure that private IP address for inbound traffic on an application gateway instance with service endpoints wherein for one of those service endpoints, you can specify the Azure Windows 10 Pro VM in it.
  ***Once specified, you need to only configure the NSG (Network Security Group) of the Azure VM to allow the traffic from the app service on that port into the Azure VM for the .NET application running on the VM***. You only need to configure the Application Gateway for outbound traffic to expose the ports used by the App service, i.e., 80 and 443 to the ports used by the Azure VM for .NET application listening socket.
- In this way, ***you can surely configure the traffic routing of the iOS app to the .NET app on the Azure VM. For more details regarding the app service routing configuration,***

For more information please refer the below link: -

***MICROSFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***App Service networking features***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#use-cases-and-features)